# Account username and password don't match on mac users & group on Mac

Tags: mac, high-sierra, password, user-account, authorization

I had to format my Mac and make a new user, the guy who formatted it for me made the acc called "USER" and I changed it to my name from users & groups.
It gave me a message that some changes will happen and I agreed anyway but now I have an admin acc that requests a username and password that won't mach any of what I used since the format, and it won't mach the login information (I have no problem logging in), I have an admin acc only and it won't give me authorization, and I can't copy to my partition drive it require authorization that I don't have and a username not changed.

[image: users and groups]

Comment: From the screenshot, the only account that is visible on your system is `USER` and it is a standard user account. The system is asking you to authenticate using an administrator's credentials.

Comment: Go see the 'guy' who formatted it for you, for some reason, he only made a standard [NOT an admin] account for you.  The admin account should have been created when the Mac was set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an admin user to manage this Mac, so why not create that first:

- [New MacBook had user accounts already; I deleted admin and can't get back in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202557/new-macbook-had-user-accounts-already-i-deleted-admin-and-cant-get-back-in)

I like my answer on that post (go figure) and then you can use the new admin credentials to fix your current user short name and home folder.

Lots of other good advice and answers here as well:

- [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

Comment: bmike's solution worked so thank you, I still wish to delete the USER acc and I can't see a way, plus my Mac uses "USER" in airdrop as a mac name and on finder it's called "USER's MacBook Pro"  tho I'm signed in from the new acc with a different name so I want it changed