# How to delete an administrator account on mac?

Tags: macos, mojave, user-account

I have an administrator account on my mac I don't need, and know the password but cannot delete it.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a second admin or just if you can remove the last remaining admin account?

Comment: There are certain circumstances which can have no admin account at all such as a question I tried answering here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354646/unable-to-boot-mac-single-user-mode-not-working/354687#354687.
@bmike

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > Users & Grops > unlock padlock > click in + > Create a new Administrator Account.

Now, you can delete the other Administrator account.

Close actual Session > Open session with the new Admin account > Go to System Preferences > Users & Groups > unlock padlock >select old Admin Account > click in -

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new admin account to be able to delete another one.